# I cant get snapshot.key swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, string, get, snapshot

This code get value snap (email, name). I need get key (RxLV2i1). How change code?

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
                let user = Subject()
                user.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
                self.subjects.append(user)
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
            }    }, withCancel: nil)
```

For example:

```
Snap (RxLV2i1) {
     email = "Test1@gmail.com";
     name = "Test1 test1";
}
```

When I change from snapshot.value to snapshot.key - show message:

> Cast from 'String?!' to unrelated type '[[String : AnyObject]]' always
>   fails

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the snapshot key, just do

```
 let key = snapshot.key
 print(snapshot.key)
```

inside of your code....

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
            let user = Subject()
            user.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)

  // Also if you add another variable called 'id' to your user object, you can set that as well to 'user.id = snapshot.key'
            let key = snapshot.key
            print(snapshot.key)

            self.subjects.append(user)
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
      }    }, withCancel: nil)
```

Comment: I need not get in console, I need UITableViewController. I want write key in user and all keys write in dictionary for show in table

Comment: Add another user variable to your User Object called 'Id' then set it where you set all of your other values. `User.Id = snapshot.key`